# Bootstrap Carousel image doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have had this problem for ages, sometimes I just give up but now I decided not to... I can't apply images to a Bootstrap Carousel, here's my css code that should work:

```
background-image: url("../img/header.jpg");
```

I'm doing a tutorial from Youtube and I do the exact way she's doing there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKWyr35srS4

And yes, I have remembered to mark the jQuery and Bootstrap js-files.
I don't know, I have had this same image issue with non-Bootstrap projects also. Should I place the image file path to both html and css?

Comment: Can you show more code please? The HTML is important. Are there any errors in your console? Is the path correct? Do background-images work? Please provide some more information

Comment: I'm trying to show more code but I'm new here, and this doesn't show the raw html code... I don't know why this doesn't show it...

Comment: check if your formatting and spaces are correct

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heyallanmoreno/7tdvu/4/)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Follow bootstrap page directly: [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Comment: if you found answer useful, please mark as best answer